# C++ CHTMLView element page loading and then disappearing

Tags: c++, mfc, temporary-files

In my C++ application, a CHTMLView is used to load some HTML into a web page. It works by writing the HTML to a temporary file, and then calling Navigate2() on the CHTMLView to navigate to the file location.

What we are finding happens is that the navigation occurs, the file is written, the completely correct contents of the page appears, but then it quickly disappears and becomes blank. But it's a visual thing; right-clicking and saying "View Source" shows the correct source, and hovering over elements on the page that react to hovering make them appear again (but everything else stays white). Resizing the window or scrolling is the only way to make everything appear.

I have tried navigating first to about:blank and then triggering a navigation to the correct place with a OnDocumentComplete() event. I have even tried navigating first to blank dummy page and then going from there. Nothing changes.

Any advice?!

The derived class is ScriptViewer.

ScriptViewer.h

```
class CScriptViewer : public CHtmlView
{
protected:
    CScriptViewer();           // protected constructor used by dynamic creation
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CScriptViewer)

// html Data
public:
    //{{AFX_DATA(CScriptViewer)
        // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add data members here
    //}}AFX_DATA

// Attributes
public:
    CAMAgentDesktopDoc* m_pDoc;
    CScriptDlg* m_pDlg;

    CString strScriptLocation;
    BOOL m_bInitialLoad;

// Operations
public:
    void GetAllValues( map<CString,CString>& mValues );
    void GetValuesIn( IHTMLDocument2* pHTMLDoc, map<CString,CString>& mValues );

// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CScriptViewer)
    public:
    virtual void OnInitialUpdate();
    virtual void OnBeforeNavigate2(LPCTSTR lpszURL, DWORD nFlags, LPCTSTR lpszTargetFrameName, CByteArray& baPostedData, LPCTSTR lpszHeaders, BOOL* pbCancel);
    virtual void OnDocumentComplete(LPCTSTR lpszURL);
    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
protected:
    virtual ~CScriptViewer();
#ifdef _DEBUG
    virtual void AssertValid() const;
    virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif

    CAMTrace m_trace;

    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CScriptViewer)
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

ScriptViewer.cpp

```
CScriptViewer::CScriptViewer()
{
    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CScriptViewer)
        // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add member initialization here
    //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
    m_trace.SetEXEName( _T("CScriptViewer") );
    m_trace.Trace( _T("constructor"), FALSE, 0 );

    strScriptLocation = _T("");
    m_bInitialLoad = FALSE;

    m_pDoc = NULL;
    m_pDlg = NULL;
}

CScriptViewer::~CScriptViewer()
{
    /*
    map<CString,CString> mValues;
    GetAllValues( mValues );
    m_pDlg->UpdateUserEnteredValues( mValues );
    */
    m_trace.Trace( _T("destructor"), FALSE, 0 );
}

void CScriptViewer::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CHtmlView::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CScriptViewer)
        // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add DDX and DDV calls here
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CScriptViewer, CHtmlView)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CScriptViewer)
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove mapping macros here.
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CScriptViewer diagnostics

#ifdef _DEBUG
void CScriptViewer::AssertValid() const
{
    CHtmlView::AssertValid();
}

void CScriptViewer::Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const
{
    CHtmlView::Dump(dc);
}
#endif //_DEBUG

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CScriptViewer message handlers

void CScriptViewer::OnInitialUpdate() 
{
    try
    {
    m_trace.Trace( _T("OnInitialUpdate") );

    ASSERT( m_pDoc );
    ASSERT( m_pDlg );
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }
}

void CScriptViewer::OnBeforeNavigate2(LPCTSTR lpszURL, DWORD nFlags, LPCTSTR lpszTargetFrameName, CByteArray& baPostedData, LPCTSTR lpszHeaders, BOOL* pbCancel) 
{
    try
    {
    map<CString,CString> mValues;
    GetAllValues( mValues );

    ASSERT( m_pDlg );

// GJS
    if (!m_pDlg) return;
    m_pDlg->UpdateUserEnteredValues( mValues );

    CString strURL = lpszURL;
    int nPosClose = strURL.Find( URL_INSTRUCTION_TO_ADAPTIVE_DESKTOP );
    if ( nPosClose > 0 )
    {
        *pbCancel = TRUE;
        CHtmlView::OnBeforeNavigate2(lpszURL, nFlags, lpszTargetFrameName, baPostedData, lpszHeaders, pbCancel);

        m_pDlg->OnScriptInstructionToDesktop( strURL.Mid( nPosClose + _tcslen(URL_INSTRUCTION_TO_ADAPTIVE_DESKTOP) ), mValues );
    }
    else
    {
        CHtmlView::OnBeforeNavigate2(lpszURL, nFlags, lpszTargetFrameName, baPostedData, lpszHeaders, pbCancel);
    }
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }
}

void CScriptViewer::OnDocumentComplete(LPCTSTR lpszURL) {
    if (!m_bInitialLoad) {
        //Navigate2(strScriptLocation);
        //m_bInitialLoad = TRUE;
    }
}




///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// accessing data values from the HTML pages, after the user has fiddled with them

void CScriptViewer::GetValuesIn( IHTMLDocument2* pHTMLDoc, map<CString,CString>& mValues )
{
    try
    {
    if ( pHTMLDoc != NULL )
    {
        BSTR bsURL;
        VERIFY( SUCCEEDED( pHTMLDoc->get_URL( &bsURL ) ) );
//      TRACE( _T("GetValuesIn(%s)\r\n"), CString(bsURL) );

        IHTMLFramesCollection2* pFrames = NULL;
        if ( SUCCEEDED( pHTMLDoc->get_frames( &pFrames ) ) )
        {
            long lNumFrames = 0;
            VERIFY( SUCCEEDED( pFrames->get_length( &lNumFrames ) ) );
            for( long l = 0; l < lNumFrames; l++ )
            {
                COleVariant v1(l);
                VARIANT vDispFrame;
                if ( SUCCEEDED( pFrames->item( v1, &vDispFrame ) ) )
                {
                    if ( vDispFrame.vt == VT_DISPATCH )
                    {
                        IHTMLWindow2* pWindow = NULL;
                        VERIFY( SUCCEEDED( (vDispFrame.pdispVal)->QueryInterface( IID_IHTMLWindow2, (LPVOID*)&pWindow ) ) );
                        ASSERT( pWindow );
                        IHTMLDocument2* pSubDoc = NULL;
                        if ( SUCCEEDED( pWindow->get_document( &pSubDoc ) ) )
                        {
                            GetValuesIn( pSubDoc, mValues );
                            pSubDoc->Release();
                        }
                        pWindow->Release();
                    }
                }
            }
            pFrames->Release();
        }

        IHTMLElementCollection* pElemColl = NULL;
        HRESULT hr = pHTMLDoc->get_all(&pElemColl);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pElemColl)
        {
            long lNumElements = 0;
            VERIFY( SUCCEEDED( pElemColl->get_length( &lNumElements ) ) );
            for( long l = 0; l < lNumElements; l++ )
            {
                COleVariant v1(l);
                COleVariant vzero((long)0);
                LPDISPATCH pDispTemp = NULL;
                VERIFY( SUCCEEDED( pElemColl->item( v1, vzero, &pDispTemp ) ) );
                ASSERT( pDispTemp != NULL );
                IHTMLElement* pel = NULL;
                VERIFY( SUCCEEDED( pDispTemp->QueryInterface( IID_IHTMLElement, (LPVOID*)&pel ) ) );

                CString str;
                BSTR bsid;
                pel->get_id( &bsid );
                VARIANT vValue;
                pel->getAttribute( CString("value").AllocSysString(), 0, &vValue );
                CString strID = CString(bsid);
                if ( !strID.IsEmpty() )
                {
                    CString strValue = _T("");
                    if ( vValue.vt == VT_BSTR ) {
                        strValue = CString(vValue.bstrVal);
                    } else if ( vValue.vt == VT_I2  ||  vValue.vt == VT_I4 ) {
                        strValue.Format( _T("%d"), vValue.intVal );
                    }

                    mValues[strID] = strValue;

//                  str.Format( _T("ID %s, value %s\r\n"),
//                              strID, strValue );
//                  strRetval += str;
                }

                pel->Release();
            }
            pElemColl->Release();
        }
        else
            ASSERT(FALSE);
    }
    else
        ASSERT(FALSE);  // passed null object doc
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }
}

void CScriptViewer::GetAllValues( map<CString,CString>& mValues )
{
    try
    {
    mValues.clear();

    LPDISPATCH pDisp = GetHtmlDocument();
    if ( pDisp )
    {
        IHTMLDocument2* p = NULL;
        if ( SUCCEEDED( pDisp->QueryInterface( IID_IHTMLDocument2, (LPVOID*)&p ) )  &&  p != NULL )
        {
            GetValuesIn( p, mValues );
            p->Release();
        }
        else
            ASSERT(FALSE);  // unable to QI for IHTMLDocument2?

        pDisp->Release();
    }
    }
    catch(...)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the code that handles the navigation:

```
CString strFilePath = CAMMiscSharedFilePaths::GetFullPathToWindowsTempDir() + _T("\\") + m_call->m_camCampaignSettings.m_scriptView.m_strName+_T("_temp.htm");
        HRESULT hr = WriteStringToTextFile( strFilePath, strRedirect );     //intentionally left for html settings, as it stores data in windows temp 

        if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) ) {
            pView->strScriptLocation = strFilePath;

            CString str = strFilePath;          
            pView->Navigate2(str);


        }
```

Comment: Post your code of CHtmlView derived class

Comment: Cheers! Added the relevant code.

Comment: Okay update: if I add a "Sleep(1000)" right before calling Navigate2() it seems to fix it. Or at least work around it. That give any clue to anyone? I would rather fix it properly...

Comment: Have you tried overriding OnBeforeNavigate2 with an empty method?

Comment: @dwo I have, yes. Unfortunately no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my derived class of a CHTMLView. I load the HTML directly into the browser. Works for me, maybe you can use it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GMHtmlView.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CGMHtmlView, CHtmlView)

CGMHtmlView::CGMHtmlView(IHtmlEventNotifier* pHEN)
{
    EnableToolTips(FALSE);
    m_pBrowser = NULL;
    m_pBrowserDispatch = NULL;
    m_pHEN = pHEN;
    m_strPrefix = "http://";
}

void CGMHtmlView::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CHtmlView::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGMHtmlView, CHtmlView)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CGMHtmlView::Create(const RECT &rect,CWnd* pParentWnd)
{
    BOOL bRet = CHtmlView::Create(NULL,NULL,WS_VISIBLE,rect,pParentWnd,AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST);

    // Pointer auf Browser herausfinden
    if(bRet)
    {
        LPUNKNOWN unknown = GetDlgItem(0)->GetControlUnknown();
        HRESULT hr = unknown->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2,(void **)&m_pBrowser);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = unknown->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch,(void **)&m_pBrowserDispatch);
    }

    return bRet;
}

void CGMHtmlView::SetPrefix(const CString& prefix)
{
    m_strPrefix = prefix;
}

void CGMHtmlView::OnBeforeNavigate2(LPCTSTR lpszURL, DWORD nFlags, LPCTSTR lpszTargetFrameName, CByteArray& baPostedData, LPCTSTR lpszHeaders, BOOL* pbCancel)
{
    CString url(lpszURL);
    url.MakeLower();

    // Sperre: alles andere als die leere Seite
    // und unser Inhalt wird gesperrt

    if(url == "about:blank")
    {
        CHtmlView::OnBeforeNavigate2(lpszURL,nFlags,lpszTargetFrameName,baPostedData,lpszHeaders,pbCancel);
        return;
    }

    if(url.Find(m_strPrefix) != 0)
    {
        *pbCancel = TRUE;
        return;
    }

    // jetzt die Adresse nach aussen weiterleiten
    if(m_pHEN)
    {
        url = url.Right(url.GetLength() - m_strPrefix.GetLength());
        m_pHEN->UrlNotify(url);
    }
}

void CGMHtmlView::Clear()
{
    if(!IsWindow(m_hWnd))
        return;

    IHTMLDocument2* pDoc = GetDocument();

    if(!pDoc)
    {
        Navigate2("about:blank");
        return;
    }

    pDoc->close();

    VARIANT open_name;
    VARIANT open_features;
    VARIANT open_replace;
    IDispatch *open_window = NULL;

    ::VariantInit(&open_name);

    open_name.vt      = VT_BSTR;
    open_name.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"_self");

    ::VariantInit(&open_features);
    ::VariantInit(&open_replace);

    HRESULT hr = pDoc->open(::SysAllocString(L"text/html"),open_name,open_features,
        open_replace,&open_window);

    if (hr == S_OK)
        Refresh();

    if (open_window != NULL)
        open_window->Release();

}

void CGMHtmlView::LoadHTML(const CString& html)
{
    if(!IsWindow(m_hWnd))
        return;

    Clear();

    IHTMLDocument2* pDoc = GetDocument();

    if(!pDoc)
        return;

    SAFEARRAY* sa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT,0,1);
    VARIANT* var;

    SafeArrayAccessData(sa,(LPVOID*) &var);
    var->vt = VT_BSTR;
    var->bstrVal = html.AllocSysString();
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(sa);

    pDoc->write(sa);
    pDoc->Release();
}

IHTMLDocument2* CGMHtmlView::GetDocument()
{
    IHTMLDocument2* document = NULL;

    if (m_pBrowser != NULL)
    {
        IDispatch *document_dispatch = NULL;
        HRESULT hr = m_pBrowser->get_Document(&document_dispatch);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (document_dispatch != NULL))
        {
            hr = document_dispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2,(void **)&document);
            document_dispatch->Release();
        }
    }

    return document;
}

void CGMHtmlView::AssertValid() const
{
    //CHtmlView::AssertValid();
}

void CGMHtmlView::PostNcDestroy()
{
    //CHtmlView::PostNcDestroy();
}
```